# UITableViewController and sub views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a screen where I want to display the details of some product. I'm using storyboards.

I have done this using a tableview with static cells, but static cells can only be done within a tableview of UITableViewController. And the problematic point is that I also want to have a Imageview within this controller. this is not possible as the tableview of a UITableViewController take all the screen size.

So I'm doing the Imageview as a subview of the tableview.

I'm wondering if it is the right way to do it, there are similar issues on stackoverflow but none is corresponding to my use case (storyboard + tableviewcontroller + staticcell + sub view)

Comment: subview approach is ok , or use Custom cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing any custom code, you could either:

1. Put a UIImageView in the table view's header or footer view.
2. Create a static cell and put the UIImageView in that. Table cells don't have to be uniform length, you could make it taller than the other cells if needed.

Comment: with option 2, if I have grouped cells, it will not be possible to have the image view static cell take all the screen wide? as the other sections will have a "margin"

Comment: @tahir If you are using a Grouped table style then the header/footer option will probably look better. If you want to match the background, you can use a generic UIView as a container and set the background color to `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`

Answer (score 1):

You can have your subclass of UITableViewController. After you initialize it take its view (tableView) and add it as subview to some other view controller. This way you can set the frame of tableView to occupy the bottom of the (top containing) view controller. To the same view controller you can add additional subviews like UIImageView and position it on the top. The only problems you will encounter might be related to missing notifications to your UITableViewController subclass (viewWillDisappear, viewDidDissappear, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, ...). But you can forward them to from your top view controller. Or you could use methods from iOS 5 to add subclass of UITableViewController as a child view controller and position it as you wish. But this is useful if you plan on supporting devices with iOS 5.0+.

See documentation of method in UIViewController:

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a UITableView as a property of the viewController and add it to vc.view, rather than subclass a UITableViewController, then set its frame as you like
- Add the imageView to vc. If you need to put it on top of the UITableView, for example, add it as the TableView's header.

Comment: it will not allow me to do static cells for the tableview, for that, I must have a UITableViewController (or subclass of it)

Comment: if there's no way around (or there is an alternative if know more about your case), then i may suggest this way: for example, if you've got only one section, then in `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` return 2, but don't put any cells in section0, except the imageview as section0's header